# At least one decimal after dot with printf in C

Tags: c, string, printing, terminal, printf

I'm looking for a way to print a floating-point number in C, which prints **at least** one decimal after the dot, but still truncates trailing zeroes, e.g.

```
double x = 5.0;
printf("<some_format>", x);
// should print 5.0, not 5, and not 5.000000

double y = 5.10;
printf("<same_format>", y);
// should print 5.1, not 5.10, and not 5.100000

double x = 5.1230;
printf("<same_format>", z);
// should print 5.123, not 5.1230
```

Also, defining a maximum or a fixed number of digits/decimals is exactly what I'm trying to avoid.

Someone knows of one format which accomplishes this with `printf` without needing to resort to writing the number to a char buffer and then manually  editing this buffer?

Comment: What have you tried? How did your attempts work or not work?

Comment: the standard stuff with %g and %f, and reading through the manual page for printf I didn't see anything regarding this matter.

Comment: This is really hard, if not impossible, since there's really no way to tell how many decimals a floating-point value really have.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, You want `5.0` to print as `5.0`, `5.10` to print as `5.1` and `5.15` to print as `5.15`...

There is no simple way to achieve this with `printf` because the problem is not so simple: `5.10` is represented in C as a `double` with a binary encoded fractional part that is an approximation of `5.1`, not an exact representation. If you print it with enough decimals, you will see that it stops producing trailing zeroes:

```
    printf("%.23f", 5.10) -> 5.09999999999999999991326
```

So your question should be:

> How to print a floating point number with at least `n` but at most `p` decimals, eliding trailing zeroes?

This can be achieved by passing `p` as the precision field of `%f` in `sprintf` and running a loop to remove the trailing zeroes beyond `n` and trailing period if `n` is `0`.

Here is an example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int print_double(double value, int n, int p) {
    char buf[400];
    int dot;
    int len;
    len = snprintf(buf, sizeof buf, "%.*f", p, value);
    if (len >= (int)sizeof(buf)) {
        printf("value too large: %g\n", value);
        return -1;
    }
    for (dot = 0; dot < len;) {
        if (buf[dot++] == '.')
            break;
    }
    while (len - dot > n && buf[len - 1] == '0')
        len--;
    if (len > 0 && buf[len - 1] == '.')
        len--;
    buf[len] = '\0';
    printf("%s\n", buf);
    return len;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    print_double(5.0, 1, 2);
    print_double(5.1, 1, 2);
    print_double(5.15, 1, 2);
    return 0;
}
```